How did anyone study the Talmud before Rashi?
Supposedly, the knowledge was transmitted from teacher to student in each generation and so Rashi learned it all from his teacher and wrote it all down.
Was it common for people to be familiar with the entire Shas?
I'm guessing his contemporaries learned everything slightly differently from their own teachers. Is all of that knowledge gone because we only kept Rashi?
Or are the differences really not that serious and everyone else knew more or less the same material, only Rashi wrote it all down?

How did anyone learn before Artscroll? Some had teachers, some figured it out, some got it wrong. Why do you think the differences were lost? There are many commentaries that have various disagreements with Rashi. He was just the most comprehensive and accessible.

@shmosel totally agree with the gist of your comment. I don't think that Rashi is the main commentary only because "he was just the most comprehensive and accessible " that is quite belittling of Rashi's great position as a Gadol of his time (and later on) as well as his accomplishment

@Yoreinu I don't see how that's belittling

"Supposedly, the knowledge was transmitted from teacher to student in each generation and so Rashi learned it all from his teacher and wrote it all down." Where did you get that from? Doesn't seem right.

A number of masechtos have the peirush of Rabbeinu Gershom. It's pretty usable.

You know who the first person to learn Gemara with Rashi was? His father.

"Or are the differences really not that serious and everyone else knew more or less the same material, only Rashi wrote it all down?" Tosefos are Rashi's students, children, and grandchildren, and they disagree with Rashi on major issues on pretty much every page in the Talmud. (Usually they do not claim that some other teacher told them otherwise.)

There were many commentaries written to the Talmud before Rashi and even a generation or so afterward. The best known is probably Rabbeinu Gershom's Peirush, which is preserved for some tractates. Very few of them were preserved, because they were superseded by Rashi's commentary. A common saying in the time of Rashi was: "Throw all the peirushim in the garbage aside from Rashi's and Rabbi Yosef Tuv Elem's." [Quoted in Shem Hagedolim of the Chida.] In the end Rabbi Tuv Elem's was also not preserved.
